# Rails ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "pg_range" does not exist LINE 3: LEFT JOIN pg_range as r ON oid = rngtypid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using an existing Postgres database for a rails 6 project. When I do some ActiveRecord queries like `User.all()`, I run into the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pg_range" does not exist
LINE 3: LEFT JOIN pg_range as r ON oid = rngtypid
```

After some googling. I found that `pg_range` was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.2. My existing database was upgraded from an older version (8.x, if I remembered correctly). Was that the reason I ran into this issue. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any PostgreSQL database of version 9.2 or above will always have a `pg_catalog.pg_range` table, be it upgraded from an older version or not.

There are two possible explanations for your error:

- You are inadvertently working with a PostgreSQL database of version 9.0 or lower.
- You somehow managed to corrupt the system catalogs by dropping `pg_range`. There are safeguards against that, so that's nothing that can happen by mistake.

Comment: Hi @Laurenz, thank you for your answer. I checked my psql version and it is 10.6 (`psql (PostgreSQL) 10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)`).  I didn't remember dropping `pg_range` myself. But it's possible that I accidentally corrupt it when upgrading system version. Any idea how I can recover it?

Comment: What you are showing is the *client* version. What is the result of the SQL statement `SHOW server_version;`?

Comment: Hi @Laurenz, I ran `SHOW server_version;` as you said in my psql shell and it was 9.1.24 I assume this was the cause of the issue? Thank you again!

Comment: Yes. That is very old and outdated software, and you shouldn't use it if you love your data.